# How to compile and deploy OpenSSL using osxcross on Linux

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, openssl, clang

I need help compiling OpenSSL using osxcross and running that on a MacOS system.
I managed to download the latest OpenSSL version from Github (3.1.4) and I compiled it using the following command:

```
CC=arm64-apple-darwin23-clang \
 RANLIB=arm64-apple-darwin23-ranlib \
 AR=arm64-apple-darwin23-ar \
./Configure darwin64-arm64 --libdir=lib/arm64 --prefix=$OSXCROSS_ROOT/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23 \ 
&& make -j23 && make install_sw
```

This compiles and installs fine. The libraries (libcrypto.dylib, libssl.dylib) are in the `$OSXCROSS_ROOT/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/arm64` folder.

I managed to compile a simple application using the below command:

```
arm64-apple-darwin23-clang++ -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' \
-I $OSXCROSS_ROOT/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/include \
-L $OSXCROSS_ROOT/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/arm64 main.cpp \
-l crypto -l ssl
```

Now when I copy the binary `a.out` (along with the OpenSSL *.dylib files) into the MacOS system and run it, I get the error:

```
dyld[768]: Library not loaded: /home/saleem/software/osxcross/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/arm64/libcrypto.3.dylib
  Referenced from: <04632F08-9238-3EF3-B3A5-29719B88CD42> /Users/saleem/Desktop/test/a.out
  Reason: tried: '/home/saleem/software/osxcross/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/arm64/libcrypto.3.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/home/saleem/software/osxcross/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/arm64/libcrypto.3.dylib' (no such file), '/home/saleem/software/osxcross/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/arm64/libcrypto.3.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

The `libcrypto.3.dylib` is in the same directory as `a.out` executable, yet I'm still getting this error.

How can I fix this please?

Also as a side question, where should I put the libraries for different architectures? Right now, I just placed them in `$OSXCROSS_ROOT/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/arm64` and `$OSXCROSS_ROOT/target/x86_64-apple-darwin23/lib/x86_64`. Is this fine or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks very much